# Expected Container behavior

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I'm building a Container in C++, within a Iterator, and i would like to "emulate" the std Containers behavior, but I can't figure out what happens to the Iterator, if between the creation and the deletion of it, the Container which refers changes.

Example:
I have a Single Liked List, and so in the iterator i have to store the pointer to the first element of the linked list which it refers to, but let's say that that we have a piece of code like

```
Iterator iter { linkedList.begin() };
linkedList.deleteFirstElement();
```

Now the pointer in Iterator points to an Object that no more exists, and so if i dereference it, it will cause a Segmentation Fault.

My question is: have I to create a copy in the Iterator of the Linked List which refers to or just justify this as undefined behavior?

Comment: oh so i should consider the iterator invalidated, and so i don't have to matter about container's changes, thanks (would you consider to makes this an answer so i can close this question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard library has many rules for iterator invalidation for each container, `std::list` for example has [`pop_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_front) which notes: "References and iterators to the erased element are invalidated".